# Use scanf to set macro

Tags: c, macros

Is it possible to use `scanf` in order to give a value to a macro substitution called `SIZE` (`#define SIZE`) but without saving the value that came with `scanf` in another variable?

Comment: The only thing you can do is use some compiler-specific flags during compilation, like [gcc's -D preprocessor option](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options), but that's far from what you're looking for.

Comment: Most likely, you are trying to solve a problem the wrong way! ;)
If you explain what you are actually trying to do, we can perhaps help you along the way - but you are just using the pointy end of a screwdriver as a hammer and wondering why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macros are evaluated at pre-compilation by pre-compiler `scanf` is evaluated by the compiler. Compiler doesn't understand macros. So no.

Comment: but i have to do an exercise which ask to make an array wich contains N values and the N must set to the program from #define comand or to put into #define somehow...how is this possible ?

Comment: @user1809300: In C, you can simple use a [variable length array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). You don't need anything else.

Comment: but the exercise title insist from me to do with #define

Comment: @user1809300: I am sorry then, its a dumb exercise.